# Usage of prepositions after adjectives

Tags: prepositions

Is it right to say: "Lazy students aren't worth of free education"
                 or "Lazy students aren't worth free education"?

Comment: You'd probably be better off using "Lazy students aren't **worthy** of free education"... I have a feeling that's what you *mean*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,

> Lazy students aren't worth of free education

doesn't mean anything to me.

If I heard

> 1. Lazy students aren't worth free education

from a native speaker, then I would understand it to mean

> 2. Lazy student are not worthy of a free education

or

> 3. It is not worth the effort to give lazy students free education.

So, in my opinion, if your goal was to try to *sound* like a native speaker and you used 1., then congratulations, I think you did a fine job. In fact, I would probably say 1.

If this was not your goal, then try to rephrase 1. to convey your true meaning.